# Apache Camel - Error in Code - PropertiesComponent with name properties must be defined in CamelContext to support property placeholders

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am creating simple Apache Camel Spring boot program to transfer a file from one directory to another.

I am using application.yml file for route properties.

I am getting below error -

> Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PropertiesComponent with name properties must be defined in CamelContext to support property placeholders. Property with key [startRoute] not found in properties from text: {{startRoute}}

If give route value hard coded in `configure()` it's working fine. But giving error on using application.xml

### POM

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.learncamel</groupId>
<artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>camel-spring-boot</name>
<description>Demo project for APache Camel using Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### application.yml

```
server:
 port: 8096

spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
---

spring: 
profiles: dev
startRoute: timer:\\fileCopyTimer?delay=5s&period=10s
fromRoute: file:C:\My_Drive\Knowledge\Apache_Camel_Tutorial\data\input?delete=true&readLock=none
toRoute: file:C:\My_Drive\Knowledge\Apache_Camel_Tutorial\data\output
message: From Dev
---

spring: 
profiles: stage
startRoute: timer:\\fileCopyTimer?delay=5s&period=10s
fromRoute: file:C:\My_Drive\Knowledge\Apache_Camel_Tutorial\data\input?delete=true&readLock=none
toRoute: file:C:\My_Drive\Knowledge\Apache_Camel_Tutorial\data\output
message: From Dev
---

spring: 
profiles: dev
startRoute: timer:\\fileCopyTimer?delay=5s&period=10s
fromRoute: file:C:\My_Drive\Knowledge\Apache_Camel_Tutorial\data\input?delete=true&readLock=none
toRoute: file:C:\My_Drive\Knowledge\Apache_Camel_Tutorial\data\output
message: From Dev
---
```

### Code file

```java
package com.learncamel.camelspringboot.route;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleCamelRoute extends RouteBuilder{

    @Autowired 
    Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception{

        try {

            from("{{startRoute}}")
                    .pollEnrich("{{fromRoute}}")
                    .to("{{toRoute1}}");

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Main Spring run code

```java
package com.learncamel.camelspringboot;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class CamelSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CamelSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### Error on run

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe" -javaagent:C:\My_Drive\Development_Tools\ideaIC-2019.1.3.win\lib\idea_rt.jar=56429:C:\My_Drive\Development_Tools\ideaIC-2019.1.3.win\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\My_Drive\Knowledge\Apache_Camel_Tutorial\camel-spring-boot\target\classes;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.11\logback-classic-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.11\logback-core-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.25\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.23\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-annotations-api\8.5.23\tomcat-annotations-api-8.5.23.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.23\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.23.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.23\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\5.3.6.Final\hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.8.10\jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.8.0\jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.8.10\jackson-core-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\apache\camel\camel-spring-boot-starter\2.20.1\camel-spring-boot-starter-2.20.1.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\apache\camel\camel-spring-boot\2.20.1\camel-spring-boot-2.20.1.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\apache\camel\camel-spring\2.20.1\camel-spring-2.20.1.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.2.11\jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.11\jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\apache\camel\camel-core-starter\2.20.1\camel-core-starter-2.20.1.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\apache\camel\camel-core\2.20.1\camel-core-2.20.1.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\adikumar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar" com.learncamel.camelspringboot.CamelSpringBootApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2019-07-24 11:50:00.555  INFO 13308 --- [           main] c.l.c.CamelSpringBootApplication         : Starting CamelSpringBootApplication on N-20HEPF10W2TB with PID 13308 (C:\My_Drive\Knowledge\Apache_Camel_Tutorial\camel-spring-boot\target\classes started by adikumar in C:\My_Drive\Knowledge\Apache_Camel_Tutorial\camel-spring-boot)
2019-07-24 11:50:00.559  INFO 13308 --- [           main] c.l.c.CamelSpringBootApplication         : The following profiles are active: dev
2019-07-24 11:50:00.676  INFO 13308 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3d680b5a: startup date [Wed Jul 24 11:50:00 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-07-24 11:50:03.285  INFO 13308 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c34a4622] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-07-24 11:50:05.190  INFO 13308 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8096 (http)
2019-07-24 11:50:05.208  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-07-24 11:50:05.210  INFO 13308 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2019-07-24 11:50:05.423  INFO 13308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-07-24 11:50:05.423  INFO 13308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4747 ms
2019-07-24 11:50:05.773  INFO 13308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2019-07-24 11:50:05.781  INFO 13308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-07-24 11:50:05.782  INFO 13308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-07-24 11:50:05.782  INFO 13308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-07-24 11:50:05.782  INFO 13308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-07-24 11:50:06.420  INFO 13308 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3d680b5a: startup date [Wed Jul 24 11:50:00 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-07-24 11:50:06.538  INFO 13308 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-07-24 11:50:06.539  INFO 13308 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2019-07-24 11:50:06.579  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-07-24 11:50:06.580  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-07-24 11:50:06.676  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-07-24 11:50:07.193  WARN 13308 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor    : No CamelContext defined yet so cannot inject into bean: routesHealthCheckRepository
2019-07-24 11:50:07.663  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.converter.DefaultTypeConverter   : Type converters loaded (core: 192, classpath: 1)
2019-07-24 11:50:08.969  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PropertiesComponent with name properties must be defined in CamelContext to support property placeholders. Property with key [startRoute] not found in properties from text: {{startRoute}}
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1831)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.initRouteInputs(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:380)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.prepareRouteImp(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:298)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.prepareRoute(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:270)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RoutesDefinition.route(RoutesDefinition.java:205)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RoutesDefinition.from(RoutesDefinition.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.from(RouteBuilder.java:169)
    at com.learncamel.camelspringboot.route.SimpleCamelRoute.configure(SimpleCamelRoute.java:17)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.checkInitialized(RouteBuilder.java:462)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.configureRoutes(RouteBuilder.java:402)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.addRoutesToCamelContext(RouteBuilder.java:383)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$1.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:1032)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$1.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:1029)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3268)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1029)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:131)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:57)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.learncamel.camelspringboot.CamelSpringBootApplication.main(CamelSpringBootApplication.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PropertiesComponent with name properties must be defined in CamelContext to support property placeholders. Property with key [startRoute] not found in properties from text: {{startRoute}}
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.getPropertyValue(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:270)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.readProperty(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:156)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.doParse(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:115)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.parse(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser.parseUri(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.parseUri(PropertiesComponent.java:235)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.parseUri(PropertiesComponent.java:178)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(DefaultCamelContext.java:2555)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinitionHelper.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(ProcessorDefinitionHelper.java:735)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.initRouteInputs(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:378)
    ... 30 more
2019-07-24 11:50:09.112  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector    : Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
2019-07-24 11:50:09.113  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector    : Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
2019-07-24 11:50:09.129  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2019-07-24 11:50:09.131  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.a.c.m.ManagedManagementStrategy        : JMX is enabled
2019-07-24 11:50:09.456  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2019-07-24 11:50:09.459  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 0 routes, of which 0 are started
2019-07-24 11:50:09.460  INFO 13308 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.330 seconds
2019-07-24 11:50:09.541  INFO 13308 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8096 (http)
2019-07-24 11:50:09.550  INFO 13308 --- [           main] c.l.c.CamelSpringBootApplication         : Started CamelSpringBootApplication in 10.001 seconds (JVM running for 11.102)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong alignment in application.yml

If want to use property as {{startRoute}}, ensure no space before property in .yml file
or use absolute path like {{spring.startRoute}}

I have tested. Issue resolved.